# Converting .htaccess rules to IIS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, iis, mod-rewrite

How can I convert the following .htaccess rules to IIS?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app/
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)/?$ user.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,NC] 
# hide .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/app/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: `Gives error` is not helpful, provide the error message and details of what happens.

Comment: Ahh.. problem resolved. Actually my hosting  site is using IIS and I installed IIS Manager to convert this rule to IIS server. Some of setting of Apache were disturbed. I am working on it. Can any one please convert these rules to IIS. Please :(

Comment: There is a `EDIT` link below your question, change the title and body of your message to reflect the new situation and explain it as detailed as possible and perhaps some one will be able to help you with it.